# Filtering records on a table data

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with tbl_contact_role and my desired output and input data of table is as follows:

contact_id role_id

1         1

1         2

1         3

2 1

2 2

3 1

4 3

Among the above mentioned table data, I want get the contact_id having roles (1,2) but not 3.

so the output for above data will be contact_id 2 as it has two specified roles that i mentioned  above i.e (1,2) and not having the role_id 3.

Desired Output:

Contact_id

2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT ContactID
    FROM ContactRoles 
   WHERE RoleID IN (1,2)
   GROUP BY ContactID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
EXCEPT 
  SELECT ContactID
    FROM ContactRoles 
   WHERE RoleID IN (3)
```

or

```
SELECT distinct C1.ContactID
  FROM ContactRoles C1 
  JOIN ContactRoles C2
    ON C1.ContactID = C2.ContactID
   AND C1.RoleID = 1
   AND C2.RoleID = 2
  LEFT JOIN ContactRoles C2 
    ON C1.ContactID = C3.ContactID
   AND C3.RoleID = 3
 WHERE C3.ContactID is null
```

But I suspect the answer from Clalusen will be the best performance

Answer (score 1):

```
select contact_id 
from tbl_contact_role
group by contact_id 
having max(role_id) = 2 
and min(role_id) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only few values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cr.contact_id
FROM dbo.tbl_contact_role cr
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl_contact_role cr2
    WHERE cr.contact_id = cr2.contact_id
    AND   cr2.role_id = 1
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl_contact_role cr2
    WHERE cr.contact_id = cr2.contact_id
    AND   cr2.role_id = 2
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl_contact_role cr2
    WHERE cr.contact_id = cr2.contact_id
    AND   cr2.role_id = 3
)
```

Not very elegant but efficient with proper indexes on `contact_id` and `role_id`.

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e83d7/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ContactID
FROM ContactRoles
GROUP BY ContactID
HAVING SUM(CASE
    WHEN RoleID IN (1,2) THEN 1
    ELSE 99 END) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3726d/2